# Qnap TS-410 deleted folder by accident anyway to recover data (raid 5 / ext4)?

Tags: raid5, ext4, data-recovery, qnap

I am not in a very good situation at the moment, and bit stressed!

I have a Qnap nas (TS-410), this operates on a Marvell 6281 800MHz CPU, while I SSH'ed into the Nas box, I deleted the wrong folder (rm -rf), Is there anyway I can get this back?

The Nas is in raid 5 and file system ext4, I have tried to run photorec (using external drive), on the Nas but I get Command not found (also tried sudo).

Any help with getting the data back would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just learn from the mistake. There are ways to potentially recover data like this, but you should be talking to a data recovery firm and not us. I don't think most people interface with their NAS via the SSH CLI. So that's another lesson...

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm assuming this is a production system in a professional environment, just restore from backup and stop fiddling around with trying to undelete the file.

Comment: Rep on this. Local backups are key for anything.